# django return file over HttpResponse - file is not served correctly

Tags: django, filestream

I want to return some files in a HttpResponse and I'm using the following function. The file that is returned always has a filesize of 1kb and I do not know why. I can open the file, but it seems that it is not served correctly. Thus I wanted to know how one can return files with django/python over a HttpResponse.

```
@login_required
def serve_upload_files(request, file_url):
    import os.path
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.init()

    try:
        file_path = settings.UPLOAD_LOCATION + '/' + file_url
        fsock = open(file_path,"r")
        #file = fsock.read()
        #fsock = open(file_path,"r").read()
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        print "file size is: " + str(file_size)
        mime_type_guess = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
        if mime_type_guess is not None:
            response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype=mime_type_guess[0])
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_name            
    except IOError:
        response = HttpResponseNotFound()
    return response
```

Edit:
The bug is actually not a bug ;-)

This solution is working in production on an apache server, thus the source is ok.

While writing this question I tested it local with the django development server and was wondering why it does not work. A friend of mine told me that this issue could arise if the mime types are not set in the server. But he was not sure if this is the problem. But one thing for sure.. it has something to do with the server.

Comment: For those who try to use this code keep in mind that the `mimetype` argument in the `HttpResponse` has been replaced with `content_type` field.

Comment: The code is basically equivalent to what the built-in [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) provides since Django 1.7.4 (released in 2015).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try passing the `fsock` iterator as a parameter to `HttpResponse()`, rather than to its `write()` method which I think expects a string.

```
response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype=...)
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators

Also, I'm not sure you want to call `close` on your file before returning `response`. Having played around with this in the shell (I've not tried this in an actual Django view), it seems that the `response` doesn't access the file until the `response` itself is read. Trying to read a `HttpResponse` created using a file that is now closed results in a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

So, you might want to leave `fsock` open, and let the garbage collector deal with it after the response is read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not change anything. response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype=mime_type_guess[0]) . The file is still not served correctly. Additionally I checked the file-size (with file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path) print "file size is: " + str(file_size)) before I return it over the HttpResponse and it returns: file size is: 56349 . Thus the file is read correctly from the file system and something went wrong when it is returned.

Comment: Tom Tom, see additions to my answer.

Comment: I agree with Ben. When fsock is added to the HttpResponse, either in the constructor or using the `write` method, it gets added to the internal stack of content that HttpResponse maintains. That stack is not evaluated until later, at the last possible moment when the response is actually needed. You'll need to leave the fsock open or else HttpResponse will raise an error when attempted to read from it. The garbage collector will take care of closing the file.

Comment: Ok thanks. I left the fsock open and I do not see the error message again. But the file-size is still 1kb :(

Comment: If you have changed the code, can you please update your question to reflect it? There are more things I could mention but it becomes possibly irrelevant if you have significantly changed the code now.

Answer (score 15):

Could it be that the file contains some non-ascii characters that render ok in production but not in development?

Try reading the file as binary:

```
fsock = open(file_path,"rb")
```

Comment: You are my savior!  All of the main posts for serving files through Django do not cover this binary necessity when serving from Windows.  By the way, setting "rb" works while using FileWrapper to serve chunks via:
return HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(filename,"rb")), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0])

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware" from your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py

I had the same problem, and after I looked around the middleware folder, this middleware seemed guilty to me and removing it did the trick for me.