# download csv file from my project path django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views

I generated a csv file through my code, and after generation, it goes to the path of my project, my project called `sample`, so the file path `sample/output.csv`.. I added a function for the download and I called this function inside the my main function ( home), but the download is not working, what I'm doing wrong?

```
def save_file(request):
   # data = open(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH,'data/table.csv'),'r').read()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output1.csv'
    return response


def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if img.is_valid():
            logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
           # paramFile = request.FILES['pic']
            paramFile =io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['pic'].file)
            portfolio1 = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
            print(type(paramFile))
            users = []
            # users = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in csv_file]
            # users = zip(*csv_file)
            #  users = [row[0] for row in csv_file]

           # for row in portfolio1:
             #   users.append(row)
            users = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in portfolio1]
            print(len(users))

            my_list = users
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
            # print(1-similarity)
            k = len(my_list)
            dist1 = np.subtract(np.ones((k, k), dtype=np.float), similarity)
            # dist1=similarity
            # dist1.astype(float)
            #print(dist1)
            # print(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[3:4], tfidf_matrix))
            # float dist = 1 - similarity;
            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))
            # arr_3d= 1- arr_3d
            #print(arr_3d)

            no_clus = 40
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
                # print (i+1910)
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='ward').fit(arr_3d[i])
                km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='complete').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = MeanShift()
                # km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                # km = MeanShift()
                #  km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                # print km
                labels = km.labels_

            csvfile = r'C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\media\images\export.csv'

            csv_input = pd.read_csv(csvfile, encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
            clus_groups = list()
            for j in range(no_clus):
                # print(" cluster no %i:%s" % (j, [my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j]))
                list_of_ints = ([my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j])
                clus_groups.append('  '.join(list_of_ints))
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
            k = len(my_list)
            dist1 = 1 - similarity

            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))
            # arr_3d= 1- arr_3d

            no_clus = 5
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
                # print (i+1910)
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='ward').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='complete').fit(arr_3d[i])
                km = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++')
                km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                # print km
                labels2 = km.labels_
                # error = km.inertia_
                print(labels2)

            labels = labels.tolist()
            labels2 = labels2.tolist()
            # new=list()


            csv_input = pd.read_csv(r'C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\output.csv',encoding='latin-1')
            labels1 = csv_input['cluster_ID']
            new_list = []
            for k in labels1:
                new_list.append(labels2[k])  # lookup the value in list2 at the index given by list1

            print(new_list)
            print(len(new_list))
            csv_input = pd.read_csv(r'C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\output.csv',encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input['User_Map'] = new_list
            csv_input.to_csv('output1.csv', index=False)

           # my_list = portfolio
            save_file(request)
           # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portfolio'))
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'labels': labels})
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

And my `home.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>Upload the CSV File to Run the Algorithm on:</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}}
         <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    {% for img in images %}
        {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
        ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
    {% endfor %}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`Url.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', 'uploader.views.home', name='labels'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Edit,** my function now is: but still not working:

```
def save_file(request):
   # data = open(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH,'data/table.csv'),'r').read()
   # file_path = r'C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\output1.csv'
   # fsock = open(file_path, "r")
    fsock= pd.read_csv(r'C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\output1.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output1.csv'
    return response
```

Comment: Edit, I put print statements inside  save_file function, and they are printing fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended it up using `FILEwrapper:`

```
def send_file(request):

  filename = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output1.csv'
  #filename= r"C:\Users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\media\output1.csv"
  download_name ="output1.csv"
  wrapper      = FileWrapper(open(filename))
  response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type='text/csv')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s"%download_name
  return response
```

Answer (score 2):

For the main issue with your download not working, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147454/1199464) because the first argument for your HttpResponse should be your data to actually send.

Now, also you should do is look at interacting with the storage classes & `MEDIA_ROOT`.

This will enable your project to work locally or remotely on a server. Looking at what you've posted I'll assume your `settings.py` contains something like `MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\media'`

You might want to consider some more generic, reusable paths in your `settings.py` (depending on how your project is structured, but this is what I have);

```
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, '../'))
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../'))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-collection')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Some good reading here would be [Managing Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/#file-storage) which takes you over the various ways to create files & access their paths.

Comment: what I have in setting.py is : MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: That's a good point, I'm reading the file path alot in my home function, how to replace this C:\users\A6B0SZZ\PycharmProjects\sample\output.csv'? I'm assuming this won't work once it's converted to the server or operated by other pc

Comment: Can you use the answer my question the way similar to the answer in the link you mentioned, I tried but didn't work either, how to specify the rows there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the file to the browser that way, the file has to be un a directory directly accessible by webserver. In most cases, the folder where all Python code is stored is not accesible.

Try to put the file in a directory accesible by webserver. Another way of sending the file is reading it through Python and sending it inline, like the user is doing in this question: [django return file over HttpResponse - file is not served correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538345/django-return-file-over-httpresonse-file-is-not-served-correctly)

Comment: I passed it now as the question you mentioned, however, it's still not working, maybe I'm not calling the function right inside the home function?

Comment: What error are you getting? File not found? Please try to add some more information to be able to resolve the issue.