# How can i display pdf in django which is stored in mysql database as blob?

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, django

In my web application, user can upload a pdf file and the same is stored in the mysql database itself. The file is stored in database using following codes.
Note : file kept in database because of security related issues.

```
    data=request.FILES['file'].read()
    fcursor = db.cursor()
    fcursor.execute("INSERT INTO REPORTS(DOC,id) VALUES(%s,%s)",(data,id))
    db.commit()
    fcursor.close()
    db.close()
```

User has provision to view this pdf. Now i transfer the pdf to template with the help of temporary files.

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT DOC FROM REPORTS WHERE id=%s",(id,))
file = c.fetchone()[0]
c.close()

f=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='/tmp/',suffix='.pdf')
f.write(filename)
f.seek(0)
response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="report.pdf"'
return response
```

But actually, i wanna display pdf directly from the database, without using the temporary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah i got the answer!. I won't need the temporary file. Its worked when i pass data read from the database with the response. I misunderstand that, it won't work until we have a stored file. But now i clear that, we have to pass the binary data with the response. Since the database holds the binary form of pdf, both data read from database and temporary file are same.

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT DOC FROM REPORTS WHERE id=%s",(id,))
file = c.fetchone()[0]
c.close()

response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="report.pdf"'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I really hope you have good enough reasons to store your .pdf files in the database. A better practice is to store uploaded docs or images in the filesystem and save their file path or url to the file on the database.
Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538345/django-return-file-over-httpresponse-file-is-not-served-correctly). The problem is probably with the way you're reading your pdf file from the database. To display the pdf directly from the database, you could try reading your blob file as binary using the `converted_file = open(file_from_db,"rb")` function. You could then do this: 
`response = HttpResponse(converted_file, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="report.pdf"'
return response`

Comment: Yeah thanks for your reply. I have done with it. I think i won't need the temporary file. In the above code, i just passed file with the response instead of f and hence it is working.